# I have a Time Machine backup server on a Raspberry PI using the latest Samba, One Mac works fine, two others do not

Tags: finder, network, time-machine, imac, smb

I have a 2017 iMac running :
System Version: macOS 11.6 (20G165) Kernel Version: Darwin 20.6.0 (Big Sur)
and a 2021 Macbook Pro (M1 Pro)
System Version: macOS 12.01 (20G165) Kernel Version: Darwin 21.1.0 (Monterey)
The iMac is backing up just fine! (only 20 hours left)

The Samba server is on a Raspberry Pi4 called silver running Samba 4.13.13 with a share called TimeMachineBackup
finder from the M1 mac connects using smb://pi@silver/TimeMachineBackup
it then prompts for name and password - I enter the smb password, it displays a dialog
There was a problem connecting to the server "silver".
you do not have permission to access the server

Windows VMs on both Macs can connect ok.
An older 2018 MacBook pro is similarly affected

the smb.conf is:

```
    [global]
   workgroup = WORKGROUP
;   interfaces = 0.0.0.0/8 eth0
;   bind interfaces only = yes

   log file = /var/log/samba/log.%m
   max log size = 1000
   logging = file
   panic action = /usr/share/samba/panic-action %d
   server role = standalone server
   obey pam restrictions = yes
   unix password sync = yes
   passwd program = /usr/bin/passwd %u
   passwd chat = *Enter\snew\s*\spassword:* %n\n *Retype\snew\s*\spassword:* %n\n *password\supdated\ssuccessfully* .
   pam password change = no
   map to guest = bad user
   ntlm auth = yes
min protocol = SMB2
fruit:nfs_aces = no
vfs objects = catia fruit streams_xattr   
fruit:aapl = yes
fruit:metadata = stream
fruit:model = MacSamba
fruit:posix_rename = yes 
fruit:veto_appledouble = no
fruit:wipe_intentionally_left_blank_rfork = yes 
fruit:delete_empty_adfiles = yes 
map to guest = bad user
spotlight = yes
unix extensions = no
browseable = yes
read only = no
inherit permissions = yes
;   logon path = \\%N\profiles\%U
;   logon drive = H:
;   logon script = logon.cmd
; add user script = /usr/sbin/adduser --quiet --disabled-password --gecos "" %u
; add machine script  = /usr/sbin/useradd -g machines -c "%u machine account" -d /var/lib/samba -s /bin/false %u
; add group script = /usr/sbin/addgroup --force-badname %g
;   include = /home/samba/etc/smb.conf.%m
;   idmap config * :              backend = tdb
;   idmap config * :              range   = 3000-7999
;   idmap config YOURDOMAINHERE : backend = tdb
;   idmap config YOURDOMAINHERE : range   = 100000-999999
;   template shell = /bin/bash
usershare max shares = 100
   usershare allow guests = yes
[TimeMachineBackup]
path = /mnt/piraid/timemachine
vfs objects = fruit streams_xattr
fruit:time machine = yes
fruit:time machine max size = 3T
[homes]
   comment = Home Directories
   browseable = yes
   path = /mnt/piraid/home/%S
   read only = no
   create mask = 0775
   directory mask = 0775
   valid users = pi, paddy
;[netlogon]
;   comment = Network Logon Service
;   path = /home/samba/netlogon
;   guest ok = yes
;   read only = yes
;[profiles]
;   comment = Users profiles
;   path = /home/samba/profiles
;   guest ok = no
;   browseable = no
;   create mask = 0600
;   directory mask = 0700
[printers]
   comment = All Printers
   browseable = no
   path = /var/spool/samba
   printable = yes
   guest ok = no
   read only = yes
   create mask = 0700
[print$]
   comment = Printer Drivers
   path = /var/lib/samba/printers
   browseable = yes
   read only = yes
   guest ok = no
;   write list = root, @lpadmin
root@silver:~# grep -v ^# /etc/samba/smb.conf
[global]
   workgroup = WORKGROUP
;   interfaces = 0.0.0.0/8 eth0
;   bind interfaces only = yes

   log file = /var/log/samba/log.%m
   max log size = 1000
   logging = file
   panic action = /usr/share/samba/panic-action %d
   server role = standalone server
   obey pam restrictions = yes
   unix password sync = yes
   passwd program = /usr/bin/passwd %u
   passwd chat = *Enter\snew\s*\spassword:* %n\n *Retype\snew\s*\spassword:* %n\n *password\supdated\ssuccessfully* .
   pam password change = no
   map to guest = bad user
   ntlm auth = yes
min protocol = SMB2
fruit:nfs_aces = no
vfs objects = catia fruit streams_xattr   
fruit:aapl = yes
fruit:metadata = stream
fruit:model = MacSamba
fruit:posix_rename = yes 
fruit:veto_appledouble = no
fruit:wipe_intentionally_left_blank_rfork = yes 
fruit:delete_empty_adfiles = yes 
map to guest = bad user
spotlight = yes
unix extensions = no
browseable = yes
read only = no
inherit permissions = yes
;   logon path = \\%N\profiles\%U
;   logon drive = H:
;   logon script = logon.cmd
; add user script = /usr/sbin/adduser --quiet --disabled-password --gecos "" %u
; add machine script  = /usr/sbin/useradd -g machines -c "%u machine account" -d /var/lib/samba -s /bin/false %u
; add group script = /usr/sbin/addgroup --force-badname %g
;   include = /home/samba/etc/smb.conf.%m
;   idmap config * :              backend = tdb
;   idmap config * :              range   = 3000-7999
;   idmap config YOURDOMAINHERE : backend = tdb
;   idmap config YOURDOMAINHERE : range   = 100000-999999
;   template shell = /bin/bash
usershare max shares = 100
   usershare allow guests = yes
[TimeMachineBackup]
path = /mnt/piraid/timemachine
vfs objects = fruit streams_xattr
fruit:time machine = yes
fruit:time machine max size = 3T
[homes]
   comment = Home Directories
   browseable = yes
   path = /mnt/piraid/home/%S
   read only = no
   create mask = 0775
   directory mask = 0775
   valid users = pi, paddy
;[netlogon]
;   comment = Network Logon Service
;   path = /home/samba/netlogon
;   guest ok = yes
;   read only = yes
;[profiles]
;   comment = Users profiles
;   path = /home/samba/profiles
;   guest ok = no
;   browseable = no
;   create mask = 0600
;   directory mask = 0700
[printers]
   comment = All Printers
   browseable = no
   path = /var/spool/samba
   printable = yes
   guest ok = no
   read only = yes
   create mask = 0700
[print$]
   comment = Printer Drivers
   path = /var/lib/samba/printers
   browseable = yes
   read only = yes
   guest ok = no
;   write list = root, @lpadmin
```

The iMac is working just fine backing up to the TimeMachineBackup share as user:pi
The MacBook pro M1 Pro can browse the pi but will not connect to pi's home or TimeMachineBackup.

How do I diagnose the issue folks? (smb logs contain no meaningful messages)

Answer (score 1):

The diagnostic was to add:
log level 2
to the smb.conf file
which revealed

```
[2021/12/06 09:58:14.130260,  0] ../../source3/smbd/dfree.c:140(sys_disk_free)
  sys_disk_free: VFS disk_free failed. Error was : Invalid or incomplete multibyte or wide character
```

The workaround is to remove the line

```
fruit:time machine max size = 3T
```

Which is not perfect but.....
Time machine now starts to work.